# What is the name of round-robins when teams play others an unequal number of times?

Tags: terminology, tournaments, schedule

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament):

> In a single round-robin schedule, each participant plays every other
>   participant once. If each participant plays all others twice, this is
>   frequently called a double round-robin. The term is rarely used when
>   all participants play one another more than twice, and **is never used
>   when one participant plays others an unequal number of times**

Let's say a tournament is held during 10 days and an entire round fits in one week exactly, no more and no less. With round I am referring to an entire cycle where each team plays every other once. The next round cannot be completed because of time constraints so there is only 3 days to organize a partial round where each teams plays a second match against *some* of the other teams but not all. So this is neither a single round-robin schedule nor a double round-robin one, but something in between. So what do you call it?

And what do you call it when each team plays the other 3 times or more? And more instances of unequal number of teams?

Comment: I'd call it "something to be avoided because it leads to great arguments when you declare a winner".

Comment: I'm not convinced any sport/league has an official name for this, but one candidate for terminology is "unbalanced schedule". Unfortunately this is also used for single round robin with home/away matches, as well as a couple of other asymmetric scheduling patterns.

Comment: I'd call it "daft" when you could have used the round robin as seeding for semifinals with a rest day beforehand.

Comment: Such a system exists in many sports leagues with a finals system (the AFL being a prominent example), but is never associated with any specific terminology. Unfortunately the answer to this question is just "there isn't one".